# How does this user's rep history make sense?

Tags: support, reputation

I just looked at the reputation history of [this user](http://politics.stackexchange.com/users/28297).  It does say that the user is not registered.  But I still don't understand how this pattern of reputation changes can happen.  Please, take a look at the history of changes in the screen capture below:

[image]

How does a user get only 1 rep for an upvote of a question?  Why would upvotes after that stop adding to their rep?  Is this a bug?  Or was this caused by some status change of the user?

Comment: Presumably they were at the repcap as a result of their question getting 40+ upvotes. They then downvoted something (-1 rep) and then got another upvote. The +5 compensated them for the loss of their 1 reputation point, but they lost four of those points to the repcap

Comment: They're currently at 198 due to a downvote (-2). If they get another upvote, it'll be worth +2 points to them, not +5 (since 3 will be lost to the repcap)

Comment: @Valorum ah.. now I do recall reading about daily cap at some point.  It doesn't happen on this particular SE site very often though, so I don't even remember where I read it.

Comment: On my home site (SFF:SE), I've lost more than half a million points to the daily cap. I think the most I've lost in a single day is into the tens of thousands.

Comment: @Valorum well, I am sorry it happened to you... if you care, that is.  I think I am remembering where I saw the cap mentioned... it was in the discussion of bounties. Bounty awards are not effected by the daily cap.

Comment: @grovkin it happens very frequently when answers get on the hot network question list. 200 rep equals merely 20 upvotes and it's pretty common to get that on a day when you have a decent (doesn't even have to be great) answer on that list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a daily rep cap of 200 per day. The only ways to go above it are to get the +15 bonus that comes when your answer is accepted or when you receive bounties.

If the user downvoted an answer at some point during the day, there will be a point at which they'll be sitting at 199 rep for the day, hence the +1 for an upvote.